# Puppeteer script with jest is failing with Error: Cannot find module 'P:\jest\bin\jest.js'

Tags: automation, jestjs, puppeteer, jest-puppeteer

I am trying to run a simple puppeteer script with jest.
**Below is my package.json contents:**

```
    {
  "name": "jest-puppeteer-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Test framework using Jest and Puppeteer",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --forceExit"
  },
  "author": "Anil Kumar Cheepuru",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest-puppeteer": "^4.4.0",
    "puppeteer": "^5.4.1"
  }
 }
```

**Below is my jest-puppeteer.config.js contents:**

```
module.exports = {
  launch: {
    headless: false,
  },
  browserContext: "default"
};
```

I have also set **preset: "jest-puppeteer"** in my jest.config.js file.

Below is the error I am getting in the console when I am trying to run the script using the command: **npm run test**

[image]

I tried to look for a solution in various sources, but no luck. Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

If you installed jest locally into your project, then this command:

```json
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest --forceExit"
}
```

won't find your locally installed jest. Try changing it to `./node_modules/.bin/jest --forceExit`:

```json
"scripts": {
    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/jest --forceExit"
}
```

Comment: Hi @pavelsaman, Thanks for the reply. I tried the solution you suggested, but that gives a different error. Below is my scripts object:
 "scripts": {
    "test": "node ./node_modules/.bin/jest --forceExit"
  }

Below is the error:
P:\CourseMaterials&Projects\Puppeteer\JEST-PUPPETEER-PROJECT\node_modules\.bin\jest:2
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
          ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1053:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:27)